# AngularJS collection from SMARTY and controller init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smarty

We just rebuild our e-commerce front-end totally into SMARTY template engine with a mix of AngularJS. I am a beginner of AngularJS and would like to test out some ways of utilizing SMARTY and AngularJS together.

So basically, what I am trying to do is fill a SMARTY array with objects, and then use the modyfier |jsonify and part the array to AngularJS.

```
<div ng-app="AppController" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init='init( {$output|jsonify} )'>
{{ testInput }}
</div>
```

Anyway, this resorts in a JavaScript error, as the angular controller cannot be found.

```
Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

If I removed the ng-controller attribute I get no error, I can then loop through the collection with ng-repeat, however I wish to use the controller a bit more and work on some custom stuff like directions and so fourth. What troubles me most is that the controller seems to be undefined, however I can easily find the app that was initialised in the console, but for some reason not the controller..

my code:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    console.log('MainCtrl initialized');
      $scope.testInput = null;
      $scope.init = function(value) {
        $scope.testInput= value;
      }
});
```

How do I initiate this controller so that it works and how to I parse the SMARTY collection to angularjs? I cannot access PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this very late update.

However, should anyone else run into the same issue. Remember to use {literal}{/literal} for your javascript within a SMARTY template.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

to:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp');
```

If that works here you have explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378733/1223357